# Is there any specific way to override search_indexes of oscar core search app?

Tags: django, search, django-haystack, django-oscar

I am using Haystack with solr back-end in Django-Oscar. I want to override ProductIndex class of core search_indexes. But, the problem is it's not working with the regular way.

Firstly, I forked the search app like other oscar apps. And I created custom ProductIndex class inside search_indexes.py file.

I also tried excluding core search_indexes in setting. But, it's not taking from the overridden app.

My custom class looks like:

```
from oscar.apps.search.search_indexes import ProductIndex as AbstractProductIndex

class ProductIndex(AbstractProductIndex):
    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        # Only index browsable products (not each individual child product)
        return self.get_model().objects.all().order_by('-date_updated')

    def read_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all().base_queryset()
```

The ProductIndex class is supposed to run from my overridden app but, instead it's using core ProductIndex app.

Updated:

I have done according to the documentation and all other forked apps are working fine. 
If I delete the index_queryset method in oscar search app, my custom method works. But, that is not what I want.

Forked apps in setting file:

```
] + get_core_apps(
    ['shipping', 'customer','promotions', 'search','checkout','catalogue',
    'partner','order','dashboard','dashboard.catalogue','dashboard.orders'],
)
```

And I have to import all from search_indexes in my init file of forked app. Otherwise, the search_indexes.py won't work at all. This is what I have done in my init file:

```
from .search_indexes import *
```

Comment: Are you sure you've correctly forked the app? Are you able to override a search view, for example? Please show us your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting where you've forked this app.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thank you for your response. I have updated further problem description in my question.

Comment: @Suryahangam have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see your stack and logs but If you use haystack with django-oscar.
Im almost sure the problem is with SearchIndex, with log smthng like ..models.Product has more than one SearchIndex please exclude one..

Its possible to exclude it in your settings.py
Smth like:

```
    HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
        'default': {
            ..
            ..
            'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['apps.search.search_indexes.ProductIndex'],
}
```